# haml - Passing variable through .haml files

Tags: haml

I have `view.haml` and `partial.haml` what I want to approach is, declare a variable in `view.haml` but print it in `partial.haml` after rendering it, I am NOT using rails or synatra or aany framework, this is just with only `haml`, how can I do this?

view.haml code:

```
-  test = 'Hello world'
!!! 5
%html{:lang => "es"}
  %head
  %body
    / Breadcrumbs
    = Haml::Engine.new(File.read(File.expand_path 'src/views/components/breadcrumbs.haml', File.dirname(__FILE__))).render
```

partial.haml

```
%section.Breadcrumbs
   %h2.Breadcrumbs-title Title
   %ul.Breadcrumbs-links
     %li
       %a{:href => "#"}
          #{test}
     %li
        %a{:href => "#"} Bread 2
     %li.active Bread 3
```

Comment: you can find the answer here: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html#render-instance_method - a good idea when using any tech is to use the docs!